# ApplicationBar is always NULL

Tags: windows-phone-7, application-bar

I have the following XAML code:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar IsVisible="True" IsMenuEnabled="False" x:Name="PageBar">
        <shell:ApplicationBarIconButton IconUri="/Assets/Icons/appbar.questionmark.rest.png" Text="Help" x:Name="HelpIcon" Click="HelpIcon_Click" />
        <shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="Help" x:Name="HelpItem" Click="HelpIcon_Click" />
            <shell:ApplicationBarMenuItem Text="About" x:Name="AboutItem" Click="AboutItem_Click" />
        </shell:ApplicationBar.MenuItems>
    </shell:ApplicationBar>
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```

But inside C# code is always `null`.

Do you know why?

Comment: At what point in the application/page lifecycle are you trying to access the application bar? Perhaps it hasn't been created at the time when you are trying to access it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found this worked for me when I wanted to change the visiblity:

```
(ApplicationBar as ApplicationBar).IsVisible = true;
```

I got that answer from [Matthew](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10420462/807396)

Answer (score 16):

In some stupid decision an ApplicationBar isn't a standard Silverlight object, because of that it doesn't really fit in the visual tree, can't be bound to and x:Name doesn't work.

You can refer to the ApplicationBar via a property on the PhoneApplicationPage.

```
var helpItem = this.ApplicationBar.MenuItems[0];
var aboutItem = this.ApplicationBar.MenuItems[1];
```

Comment: You can also create the ApplicationBar in code and then be able to reference it by name.