# Get Application Bar from Parent - Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, mvvm, application-bar

I'm using MVVM architecture in a WP7 phone app. My current view is a user control, which exists inside of a parent page (standard page -- not stand-alone user control). I have passed the main page as a parent to a "parent" property of the user control, and I can access pretty much any control in the parent. For example: this works to access a lockable pivot in the parent:

```
Dim p As LockablePivot
p = MyParent.FindControl("myLockablePivot")
If p IsNot Nothing Then
..do something with the pivot
End If
```

My problem is in accessing the ApplicationBar in the parent. This does not work. I have triple checked the x:Name assigned to the application bar. (null reference exception):

```
    Dim ap As ApplicationBar
    ap = MyParent.FindName("appBar")

    ap.IsVisible = False
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I hit the same issue, but as Nigel points out in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933109/applicationbar-is-always-null), the

> "ApplicationBar isn't a standard Silverlight object, because of that it doesn't really fit in the visual tree, can't be bound to and x:Name doesn't work."

It turns out that there is an [ApplicationBar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.controls.phoneapplicationpage.applicationbar(v=vs.92).aspx) property on the PhoneApplicationPage class.  You can use it to access the Application Bar and then grab the Buttons or MenuItems from there.

Here is a C# example of what I did in my page constructor to localize the text:

```
public MyPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    (this.ApplicationBar.Buttons[0] as ApplicationBarIconButton).Text = AppResources.event_add_menu_item;
}
```

Admittedly, using the index to locate the item and then having to cast is unfortunate, but at least it works!